# CouchDB filter timestamps in a reduce function - some sort of Date.now?

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

Can a Date.now type function be used in either map or reduce functions?  Can it be used anywhere at all?
More specifically, the view must not cache the Date.now value.
Here is what I tested that only worked for the first run after a change to any view function:

```
function (doc){
  var n = new Date();
  if(doc.TimeStamp > n.getTime() - 30000){
    emit(doc._id, doc);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the answer to this is really that "Date()" is a oneshot.  So in a view's map function its called at the time that map is called, during the view's indexing.  I think the same holds true for the recude() function, so the answer is probably No, Date() cannot be used unless we are OK with it being a oneshot.  My original intent was to get documents that were newer than 30 seconds old (for instance).  I've used the startKey mechanism to do this, by emit(doc.TimeStamp, doc.usefulField);  Now timestamp is the key and can be queried sequentially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The view rows will be refreshed only when the particular doc gets updated. But you can request the view for that result: emit the doc.TimeStamp as key and request the view with ?startkey=timestamp where timestamp is the value of now.getTime() - 30000.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  `var now = new Date()` should work.

The condition must result in `false`. You can test it with the view:

```
function (doc) {
  var now = new Date()
  var timestamp = now.getTime()

  emit(timestamp,null)
}
```

It will respond something like

```
{
  "total_rows":1,
  "offset":0,
  "rows" :[{
   "id":"ecd99521eeda9a79320dd8a6954ecc2c",
   "key":1429904419591, // timestamp as key
   "value":null
  }]
}
```

Make sure that `doc.TimeStamp` is a number (maybe you have to execute `parseInt(doc.TimeStamp)`) and greater then `timestamp - 30000`

Two words about your line of code `emit(doc._id, doc);`:

1. To emit `doc._id` as key means maybe you doesn't need the view. Simply request the doc by `GET /databasename/:id`. Also to include `doc._id` in multipart keys or the value of the view row is mostly not necessary because its included in every row automatically as additional property. One valid reason would be when you want to sort the view over the doc ids.
2. To emit the `doc` as value is not recommended for performance reasons of the view. Simply add `?include_docs=true` when you request the view and every row will have an additional property `doc` with whole doc in it.

Comment: Could you provide an example?  I will add my code that didn't work.  it was caching the value from the time when the view was compiled.

Comment: Thanks for the additional detail.  Have you run this code?  I just tried it and I get the same result that I am having, where the timestamp value is the same no matter how many times i refresh.  is there a config that needs to be set?  I also tried in two different browsers, so its not a browser caching issue.  Regarding the emit(doc._id, doc); this was just a quick way to show my problem.  I have a few fields pulled out, this was simpler to type.

Comment: Ah. Now i understand what you expect: you want to receive all rows that have a timestamp not older then `now.getTime() - 30000`.

Comment: Yes, can this be done?  I have tested the now.getTime() works in the reduce function (kinda makes sense based on how its supposed to work).  Trying to figure out the right function to eliminate keys that have too old of timestamp

Comment: The view rows will be refreshed only when the particular doc gets updated. But you can request the view for that result: emit the `doc.TimeStamp` as key and request the view with `?startkey=timestamp` where `timestamp` is the value of `now.getTime() - 30000`.